# How .NET determines equal objects in LINQ "select new"?

Tags: .net, linq, equals, equality

Here is example:

```
class A
{ 
    public long ParentId; 
    public string ParentName; 
    public string Name; 
}

// list is IEnumerable<A>
var selected = list
    .Select(x => new {
        parent = new {
            id = x.ParentId,
            name = x.ParentName
        }
        name = x.Name
    });
var grouped = selected.GroupBy(x => x.parent);
```

So, as grouping completed successfully, I make conclusion, that `parent` is not created for two different entities if both of them have the same `ParentId` and `ParentName`. By other words, if `list[i].ParentId == list[j].ParentId` and `list[i].ParentName == list[j].ParentName`, then after selecting `selected[i].parent == selected[j].parent`.
Am I right? I thought, that `new` creates new object on every iteration through source collection. How .NET does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of how Equals is impemented. For anonymous classes it's returns true if and only if the properties match and for each of the properties there is equality.

Compare these two:

```
Console.WriteLine(new { A = 1, B = "a" } == new { A = 1, B = "a" });  //false
Console.WriteLine(new { A = 1, B = "a" }.Equals(new { A = 1, B = "a" }));  //true
```

Answer (score 1):

`GroupBy` uses a standard hash+equals approach (common with `Hashtable`, `Dictionary<,>`, etc), which is to say:

- `GetHashCode` defines definite non-equality (when different) and *possible* equality (when same)
- Equals (`IEquatable<T>.Equals` or `object.Equals`) defines equality

Your group by projection compares `ParentName`, so that is used when comparing items. Since `string` has well defined `GetHashCode`/`Equals`, this works fine.

Re your final question:

> I thought, that new creates new object on every iteration through source collection.

Strictly, yes. But it only enumerates it once, so that isn't an issue. Even if it didn't, the anonymous type `new {...}` *itself* has an equality definition based on the component members.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't call `==` operator.

It asks [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if instances are equal.
In turn, it calls [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) from [`IEquatable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) implementation, if there is any, or [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method as the last resort.

> The default implementation of `Equals` supports reference equality for reference types, and bitwise equality for value types.

However you are free to override the method if you need to set up your own rules for equality.

In your example, `parent` if of an anonymous type. C# compiler generates field-by-field `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations because obviously you can't provide them yourself.

Comment: Do you mean, that `parent` in this case is value type?

Answer (score 0):

Each .Net object implements the IComparer interface and has it's own implementation of the CompareTo method.  .Net just uses this method to determine whether something is equal, in this case .net is just checking that both objects public properties have the same values therefore they are equal.

EDIT: Sorry I was confusing IComparer CompareTo with object.Equals, each object implements the Equals method and as an example String class overrides this method and just checks that both strings contain the same value not reference the same memory address.

Comment: This is wrong. `System.Object` [doesn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) implement `IComparable` (this is what you probably mean).

Comment: But 2 different instances of `A` will not be equal if their's fields equal.

Answer (score 0):

Well to override the defualt comparison behaviour of .Net you should do something like this:

```
class A
{ 
    public long ParentId; 
    public string ParentName; 
    public string Name; 


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(A))
            return false;
        var other=(A) obj;
        return Equals(other.ParentId, ParentId) && Equals(other.ParentName, ParentName);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (ParentName.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ ParentId.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the best way. Instead, you should implement `IEquatable<A>` and call its `Equals` from “plain object” `Equals`.